# Function that can tell where the roulette stoped

Tags: javascript, html, css

Hello I'm making a roulette game using HTML/CSS/JS. I have a problem to make a function that can tell where the roulette stoped. The roulette is randomizing a pixel number up to 20000 than the background-img change its position to that randomized number. There is 15 circles. 7 red, 7 blue and 1 green at the end. I tried to make a function that takes the randomized number and if the number is odd than the color is blue, if its even than its red and every 15 is green. **Thee problem comes when the background img repeats. The even numbers are now odd and the odd are even. Do you guys have any solution for that?** [image]

```
function resolveColor(number) {
  if (number % 15 === 0) {
    return 'green';
  }
  if (number % 2 === 0) {
    return 'red';
  }
  return 'blue';
}

const x = Math.ceil(Math.random()*20000);
console.log('Generated number: ', x);
console.log('Result is: ', resolveColor(x));
```

Comment: Sure.  How about adding some HTML attributes to the actual elements, and reading _that_ instead of using modulus?

Comment: I'm looking for a Js solution but that was a good idea anyway

Comment: Just look at `(number % 15) % 2)`

Answer (score 1):

To expand on what I already said in the comments:

You want to take a randomly-generated number, which is potentially very large, and see whether its reduction modulo 15 (that is, its remainder on division by 15) is even or odd. While it's not common to have nested `%` operators, and wouldn't usually make much sense, here doing so is an exact match for your problem. `number % 15` is a number from 0 to 14 (inclusive) which tells you the remainder if you divide `number` by 15 - this represents which of the 15 parts of the "roulette wheel" you are ending up on. And then you can easily check what colour this is in exactly the way you already are.

So the full code would be:

```js
function resolveColor(number) {
  var reduced = number % 15;
  if (reduced === 0) {
    return 'green';
  }
  if (reduced % 2 === 0) {
    return 'red';
  }
  return 'blue';
}

const x = Math.ceil(Math.random()*20000);
console.log('Generated number: ', x);
console.log('Result is: ', resolveColor(x));
```

An aside: this isn't really any different from generating  a random number from 0 to 14. In fact, the only difference in output is that the code here *won't* generate the expected distribution of colours in the long run - because your "ceiling" of 20,000 is not a multiple of 15. This can be fixed by using 15,000 or 30,000 (or any other multiple of 15) instead of 20,000.

Answer (score -1):

This is a very interesting question!

What I could think of so far is to use a loop to toggle the state.

The comments in the code below for further explanation:

```js
function resolveColor(number){
  // Return color straight away
  // because no further operation required
  if (number % 15 === 0){
    return 'green';
  }

  // Use a variable to decide its state
  var oddIsBlue = true;

  // For every cycle, toggle the state
  // i += 15 so that amount of loops is minimised
  for (var i = 15; i <= number; i += 15){
    if (i % 15 === 0)
      oddIsBlue = !oddIsBlue;
  }

  // Return color depending on state
  // I'm using ternary expression for shorter code
  if (number % 2 === 0){
    return oddIsBlue ? 'red' : 'blue';
  }

  return oddIsBlue ? 'blue' : 'red';
}


console.log('Number  1 is color: ' + resolveColor(1));
console.log('Number 16 is color: ' + resolveColor(16));
console.log('Number 31 is color: ' + resolveColor(31));
console.log('Number 46 is color: ' + resolveColor(46));
console.log('Number  2 is color: ' + resolveColor(2));
console.log('Number 17 is color: ' + resolveColor(17));
console.log('Number 32 is color: ' + resolveColor(32));
console.log('Number 47 is color: ' + resolveColor(47));
console.log('Number 15 is color: ' + resolveColor(15));
console.log('Number 30 is color: ' + resolveColor(30));
console.log('Number 45 is color: ' + resolveColor(45));
console.log('Number 60 is color: ' + resolveColor(60));
```

Comment: This is a very convoluted and (to me) confusing way to do this - when it's actually a very simple problem (see my comment on the question).

Comment: Thanks for help this is exacly what I needed!